# Fragment no visible if using fragment manager and nav controller

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

I'm trying to build an app with a single Activity.

In my main fragment once the user taps a button, I need to set a fragment in the current main fragment ( using fragment manager ) and at the same time I navigate to another fragment ( using nav comp )

Fragment manager code:

```
fragmentManager?.let { fragmentManager ->

            val fragment = ProtocolRunningCompaqFragment.newInstance()
            fragment.arguments = bundle

            val transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()

            fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragmentProtocolRunningCompaqContainer, fragment, PROTOCOL_RUNNING_COMPAQ_FRAGMENT_TAG)
                    .commit()

            Log.d("FragmentManager", "count: ${fragmentManager.backStackEntryCount}")

        }?: run {

            Log.d("Error","The fragment manager is not available")
        }
```

After that in the same thread I do:

```
findNavController().navigate(directions)
```

This is the layout for the main fragment manager where and I insert the new fragment in the `fragmentProtocolRunningCompaqContainer`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".ProtocolListFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/black_border"
            android:id="@+id/fragmentProtocolRunningCompaqContainer"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/progressBar">

        </FrameLayout>
....
</FrameLayout>
```

The problem is when the Nav controller do the navigation, when I press the back arrow, the fragment inserted with the fragment manager is not visible, with `protocolRunningCompagFragment.isVisible` equals to false

After a lot of testing, I've noticed that if I use `commitNow()` instead of `commit()` I can see the fragment inserted for one second and then it performs the navigation. But when I come back the fragment is not visible.

It has to be something between fragment manager and nav controller because if I comment out the code for the nav controller, the fragment is inserted with no problems.

I'm a bit new in android so, sorry if I'm doing something barbaric :)

Comment: can you show onBackPressed() method code?

Comment: I don't have any onBackPressed() method, should I have one? The animation in the navController when I press the back button is done right.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think I found the answer.

The problem is I was using the `fragmentManager`, when actually I should use the `childFragmentManager`.

As I could understand, the `childFragmentManager` deals with fragments inside of a fragment: `Return a private FragmentManager for placing and managing Fragments inside of this Fragment.`

So now it works:

```
        val fragment = ProtocolRunningCompaqFragment.newInstance()
        fragment.arguments = bundle

        childFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragmentProtocolRunningCompaqContainer, fragment, PROTOCOL_RUNNING_COMPAQ_FRAGMENT_TAG)
                .commit()
```